# Official information on `arguments` in ES6 Arrow functions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

```
(() => console.log(arguments))(1,2,3);

// Chrome, FF, Node give "1,2,3"
// Babel gives "arguments is not defined" from parent scope
```

According to Babel (and from what I can tell initial TC39 recommendations), that is "invalid" as arrow functions should be using their parent scope for arguments.  The only info I've been able to find that contradicts this is a single comment saying this was rejected by TC39, but I can't find anything to back this up.

Just looking for official docs here.

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-arrow-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation - see the notes

Comment: Chrome gives the same now... `:)`

Comment: Chromium 67 throw an error here.

Comment: Webpack/Babel indicates this issue with this error message: "Parsing error: 'arguments' is not allowed in class field initializer".

Comment: @totymedli -- They didn't 3 years ago, yay progress!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Chrome, FF, and node seem to be wrong here, Babel is correct:

Arrow functions do not have an own `arguments` binding in their scope; no arguments object is created when calling them.

> looking for official docs here

Arrow function expressions evaluate to functions that [have their [[ThisMode]] set](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-functioninitialize) to `lexical`, and when such are called the [declaration instantiation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation) does not create an [`arguments` object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arguments-exotic-objects). There is even a specifc note (18 a) stating that "*Arrow functions never have an arguments objects.*".

Comment: Currently Chrome arrow function throws an exception when try to access `arguments`

Answer (score 54):

As noted by Bergi, arrow functions do not have their own `arguments` variable.

However, if you do want to capture the args for your arrow function, you can simply use a [rest parameter](http://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#default-rest-spread)

```js
const myFunc = (...args) =>
  console.log ("arguments", args)
  
myFunc (1, 2, 3)
// arguments [1, 2, 3]
```

Rest parameters can be combined with other positional parameters, but must always be included as the *last* parameter

```js
const myFunc = (a, b, c, ...rest) =>
  console.log (a, b, c, rest)

myFunc (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
// 1 2 3 [ 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
```

If you make the mistake of writing a rest parameter in any other position, you will get an Error

```js
const myFunc = (...rest, a, b, c) =>
  console.log (a, b, c, rest)
  
myFunc (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
// Error: Rest parameter must be last formal parameter
```

Comment: Yeah, but the transpiled version of that is a for loop over the arguments; significantly more code added

Comment: `/me shrugs` - I guess I don't really care about the transpiled output in most cases. There's more code added sure, but it's not like it doesn't work. If you care about transpiled output, you probably shouldn't be using a transpiler in the first place. I mean, just look at the transpiled output for a generator or destructuring assignment...

Comment: The point is ES6 affords you a much more succinct/expressive/readable *source* code. The build code output should not matter too much so long as it still performs to your expectations.

Comment: `Yeah but... who cares ?` -- I do, at least for what I'm working on right now. In general, I agree, but the needless `for (var _len = arguments.length, args = Array(_len), _key = 0; _key < _len; _key++) { args[_key] = arguments[_key]; }` is too heavy for my current project when I'm doing things like writing function language helpers (`map = (...args) => flip(args)`).  Having that extra code 20 times is far too much. It's not an issue of it expanding into more source than the original, it's an issue of it expanding into _significantly_ more source than I could write myself (your 2nd ex is good)

Comment: But this whole thing is off-topic for this question anyway ;)

Comment: Javascript does have a *new* (since version 1?) keyword that does exactly that: `function`: `const log = function(){console.log.apply(console,arguments);}` :)