# What is the third parameter thisArg in Array.from method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Array **from** method can be called with argument *items* and optional arguments *mapfn* and *thisArg*.

```
Array.from(items, mapfn, thisArg);
```

The following simple example demonstrate crating new Array using *mapfn* with multiply logic inside for each items value.

```
Array.from('123', (item, index) => item * 2); // [2, 4, 6];
```

What is the third argument? Please give me an example which will showing the case when i should use *thisArg*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third parameter is

> *Value to use as this when executing mapFn.*

```js
const x = Array.from('123', function(item) {
  console.log("THIS", this);
  return item * 2;
}, {
  test: "valueOfThis"
});

console.log("Result:", x);
```

ES6 version

```js
const that = { test: "ValueOfThis" };
const x = Array.from('123', (item) => {
  console.log("THIS", that);
  return item * 2;
});

console.log("Result:", x);
```

Comment: Can we use arrow function for `function(item)`?

Comment: I tried it but it gives me *Undefined* value for `this.test` and it gives me `Object window` value for `this`. It is also applied for the arguments usage of arrow function. It is referred from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935336/official-information-on-arguments-in-es6-arrow-functions. It does not work

Comment: I thought it will be like this but does not work `const x = Array.from('123', (item) => {
  console.log("THIS", this);
  return item * 2;
}, {
  test: "valueOfThis"
});`

Answer (score 4):

thisArg is Optional

- Value to use as `this` when executing mapFn.

```js
a = Array.from('2431', function(item){
  return item*this.multiply;
}, {multiply:2});
console.log(a)
// will return : [4, 8, 6, 2]
```

and it's identical to:

```js
a = Array.from('2431', (item, index) => item * 2);
console.log(a)
// will return : [4, 8, 6, 2]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from