# Why can't I return an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, higher-order-functions, arrow-functions

I have a little higher-order sorta function here.

While this works as expected:

```
var square = (a) => a * a;

var callAndLog = (func) => {
  return function () {
    var res = func.apply(undefined, arguments);
    console.log("Result is: " + res);
    return res;
  }
};

var squareAndLog = callAndLog(square);

squareAndLog(5);  // Result is 25
```

This here, when i return an arrow function insted, doesn't work:

```
var square = (a) => a * a;
var callAndLog = (func) => {
  return (() => {
    var res = func.apply(undefined, arguments);
    console.log("Result is: " + res);
    return res;
  })
};
var squareAndLog = callAndLog(square);
squareAndLog(5); // Result is NaN
```

I know that arrow functions are loose, that's why i try here returning it within the parantheses `()`. It doesn't work without them either.

Comment: `squareAndLog(5); // Result is NaN` — I can't reproduce the problem. When I run that code, it throws an exception: "ReferenceError: arguments is not defined

Comment: Arrow functions [do not bind arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_arguments), so in your second example you're not applying what you expected. Use `(...args) => ...` instead. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935336/official-information-on-arguments-in-es6-arrow-functions) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch) for further details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrow functions doesn't have the `arguments` object, instead you can use the [**rest parameter syntax**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) (`...`) like this:

```js
var square = (a) => a * a;
var callAndLog = (func) => {
  return ((...args) => {
    var res = func.apply(undefined, args);
    console.log("Result is: " + res);
    return res;
  })
};
var squareAndLog = callAndLog(square);
squareAndLog(5);
```

Answer (score 9):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not bind its own `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target`.

Arrow functions don't bind an `arguments` object to their body. Your function relies on the use of `arguments`, so it won't work as an arrow function.

As suggested in the comments above, you can use `...args` instead:

```js
var square = (a) => a * a;
var callAndLog = (func) => {
  return (...args) => {
    var res = func.apply(undefined, args);
    console.log("Result is: " + res);
    return res;
  };
};
var squareAndLog = callAndLog(square);
squareAndLog(5);
```

> I know that arrow functions are loose, that's why i try here returning it within the parantheses ().

Enclosing your arrow function in parentheses has no effect on its behavior. There are few (if any?) situations where it would.

Comment: But shouldn't it give a `ReferenceError`? Or is it somehow browser dependent?

Comment: @AndrewLi If OP's code is contained in some other non-arrow function that's enclosing it, then `arguments` would refer to the `arguments` object from whenever that outer function was called.

Comment: I understand that, but Quentin seems to suggest differently. Maybe some browsers treat it differently?

Comment: @AndrewLi I don't see Quentin saying that the code above is in the outermost scope. He may have just neglected to mention that detail.