# understanding lexical arguments in ES2015

Tags: ecmascript-6

I was looking at:

https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/

And it has the following example:

```
// Lexical arguments
function square() {
  let example = () => {
    let numbers = [];
    for (let number of arguments) {
      numbers.push(number * number);
    }

    return numbers;
  };

  return example();
}

square(2, 4, 7.5, 8, 11.5, 21); // returns: [4, 16, 56.25, 64, 132.25, 441]
```

and I was trying to understand what was really happening here:
specifically can someone explain why does square use an internal arrow function instead of just performing the required actions?
could this not be re-written to be:

```
function square() {
    let numbers = [];
    for (let number of arguments) {
      numbers.push(number * number);
    }

    return numbers;
}
```

What does the extra wrapping in "example" change in the behavior of this function?

Comment: It's just a toy example and not meant to be useful (compare `square = (...nums) => nums.map(x => x*x);`). It just demonstrates [how `arguments` works inside an arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30935336/1048572).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply demonstrates that `arguments` in the arrow function refers to `arguments` of `square` function. this is not true with a simple function :

```
function square() {
  let example = function() {
    let numbers = [];
    for (let number of arguments) {
      numbers.push(number * number);
    }

    return numbers;
  };

  return example();
}

square(2, 4, 7.5, 8, 11.5, 21); // returns: []
```

Comment: This is exactly right.
    `let example = () => { ... };`
is ECMAScript6 for
    `let example = function () { ... };`
Personally I don't find the new => construct to be a net benefit.  Anything that decreases the readability of the code for no clear reason ought to be left out.

Comment: @bearvarine the benefit of the arrow function is to use `arguments` and `this` key words to refer to the parent function instead of the current function