# How to validate the number of arguments in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I (only) use `arguments` to throw an error when an invalid number of arguments are passed to a function.

```
const myFunction = (foo) => {
  if (arguments.length !== 1) {
     throw new Error('myFunction expects 1 argument');
  }
}
```

Unfortunately in TypeScript I get the error `The 'arguments' object cannot be referenced in an arrow function in ES3 and ES5. Consider using a standard function expression.` when referenced in arrow function.

How can I (always) validate the number of arguments in TypeScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Official information on \`arguments\` in ES6 Arrow functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935336/official-information-on-arguments-in-es6-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code snippet that you posted doesn't seem to have the same error for me.  I do see that error if I change it to be an arrow function:

```
const myFunction = (foo) => {
    if (arguments.length !== 1) {
        throw new Error('myFunction expects 1 argument');
    }
}
```

You can try doing something like:

```
const myFunction = (...foo) => {
    if (foo.length !== 1) {
        throw new Error('myFunction expects 1 argument');
    }
}
```

To work around the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can also enforce the arity of your function in compile-time:

```
const myFunction = (...args: [any]) => {
  /* ... */
}
```

```
myFunction(1);    // OK
myFunction(1, 2); // Compile-time error
```