# Improper behavior with Arguments object in arrow function while using it in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

argument.length always returns 5 while gives an error in browser

I know that arrow functions does not have arguments then why it is returning 5.

`t =()=>{
console.log(arguments.length)
}
t();`

arguments.length should have return error or 0

Comment: In arrow functions use rest parameters, eg.  `t =(...args)=>{ console.log(args.length) }`  In fact in none arrow functions use rest parameters as there just better.

Answer (score 3):

The arrow function returns 5 because of using node,an arrow function inside a regular function

Arrow functions don't really have an arguments object.You can refer this for more information [Official information on `arguments` in ES6 Arrow functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935336/official-information-on-arguments-in-es6-arrow-functions)

**But why does it always return 5 and not undefined??** 
The reason behind this is in node your arrow function is wrapped around in a regular function while using the node command. And as regular functions have *arguments* this argument is being used by your arrow function.
When you execute your arrow function it does not find arguments in its execution context and goes a level up to find it and as your function is wrapped by a normal function by node it finds the **arguments** object and uses it.
Although this behavior will only be shown in node and not in browser as it will not have **arguments** in any execution context.

The reason why 5 is being returned is because the 5 arguments are (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) and an easy way of confirming this is make an error in your on the very first line of the JS file.

Comment: Thanks !! Nice explanation.