# Different output when using arguments in arrow function between node js console and browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, arguments, arrow-functions

The doc here 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_arguments
says Arrow functions do not have their own arguments object. 
So it should be undefined when we use it in an arrow function.
But I got different results between `nodejs console` and the `browser`(Firefox Developer 70.0b2).

I searched the Internet, but cannot find official doc for this.

```
let arrowFun = () => {
  console.log(arguments);
};

arrowFun("a", "b", "c");
```

1. In Nodejs console, I expect the output to be undefined, but the actual output is:

```
[Arguments] {
      '0': {},
      '1':
       { [Function: require]
         resolve: { [Function: resolve] paths: [Function: paths] },
         main:
          Module {
            id: '.',
            exports: {},
            parent: null,
            filename: 'e:\\workspace\\firefox-webide-test\\test\\app.js',
      ... omitted for brevity ...
}
```

2. In browser, I got the right output: undefined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Official information on \`arguments\` in ES6 Arrow functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935336/official-information-on-arguments-in-es6-arrow-functions)

Comment: I just ran it in node console and it worked as you expected

Comment: @DimitarNestorov the node console is another thing

Answer (score 1):

That's because [NodeJS silently wraps your modules into an IIFE to provide module-scoped variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15411236/5260024) (e.g. `module` and `exports`). That's the `arguments` you are seeing (it's not that `arguments` doesn't exist in arrow functions, it is lexically scoped just like `this`, so in both cases it points to the surrounding `arguments`²).

---

²proof:

```js
function surrounding() {
  (() => console.log(arguments))();
}

surrounding("you see");
```