# Arrow function output in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I was reading about arrow function in js. There I found one question.

```js
var arguments = [1, 2, 3];
var arr = () => arguments[2];
console.log(arr());

function foo(n) {
  var f = () => arguments[0] + n;
  return f();
}
console.log(foo(3));
```

It's output is showing 6.
Can anyone explain why it is so?

Comment: You do `arguments[0]` which is 3 and then you add `n` which is also 3. That does 6

Comment: @polypode How arguments[0] = 3 ?

Comment: `arguments` within your `foo` function is not the `var arguments` defined previously. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: What do you expect instead? `arguments` and arrow functions are documented on MDN ([`=>`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), [`arguments`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)) and in the [specification](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function-calls).

Comment: Strongly related: [No binding of arguments in JavaScript](/q/46032751/4642212). I mean… this example is taken from MDN; you were reading MDN. MDN links to its article about `arguments` and it’s explained very clearly there. I really don’t see what else you were expecting this code to do or how you could miss what `arguments` is.

Answer (score 2):

[`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) is the object for getting the arguments of the function called. Therefore `arguments[0]` is the argument `n`.

You need to change the name of the array such as `arr = [1,2,3]` and use it in the `foo()` function `f = () => arr[0] + n`;

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var bar = () => arr[2];
console.log(bar());

function foo(n) {
  var f = () => arr[0] + n;
  return f();
}
console.log(foo(3));
```

Comment: Neither the `arr` function nor the external `argument` has anything to do with the original question and the result the they got which was 6

Comment: Okay so this argument inside foo() is a new arguments .It has nothing to do with above argument array.

Comment: @smac89 what about console.log(bar()); line? It is also printing

Comment: @Deepaksoni the only function call in your question that prints 6 is the `foo(3)`

Comment: Slight correction... `arguments` is the object for getting the arguments of the _regular_ function called. Arrow functions do not have access to that `arguments` but they will have access to anything in scope

Comment: In addition to @Phil 's comment, you can have a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935336/official-information-on-arguments-in-es6-arrow-functions